# Выборка из базы между интервалом времени

Tags: php, mysql

В таблице в строках имеется поле varchar(10). В нем храню дату формата ДД.ММ.ГГГГ? Как выбрать строки в интервале от xx.yy.zzzz до aa.bb.cccc? При этом для каждой даты есть по 4 строки и пронумерованы 0-3 в отдельном поле. Нужно чтобы сортировка шла по датам от 0 до 3:

```
xx.yy.zzzz 0
xx.yy.zzzz 1
xx.yy.zzzz 2
xx.yy.zzzz 3
.....
aa.bb.cccc 0
aa.bb.cccc 1
aa.bb.cccc 2
aa.bb.cccc 3
```

ЗЫ. Таблица старая и структуру изменить никак. Записей дофига :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кто же так хранит даты в базах :)

Для даты и времени есть специальные типы данных `DATE` и `DATETIME`. А выбирать интервалы можно запросом типа:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE date_field BETWEEN "2012-01-01" AND "2012-01-31"
```

С сосртировкой:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE date_field BETWEEN "2012-01-01" AND "2012-01-31"
ORDER BY date_field, ind_field
```

Где `date_field` - дата, а `ind_field` - индекс 0-3

Comment: А если я тип поля изменю на DATE формат ДД.ММ.ГГГГ сработает для выборки?

Comment: Не, так просто не получится. Нужно добавить в таблицу еще одно поле с типом DATE. Заполнить его запросом UPDATE через функцию преобразования ДД.ММ.ГГГГ в стандартный формат даты MySQL ГГГГ-ММ-ДД. И, если на сайте формат пользовательского ввода ДД.ММ.ГГГГ, то в php перед записью в базу дату преобразовывать в ГГГГ-ММ-ДД.

Comment: Спасибо. Переписываю)

Comment: Это правильное решение. Удачи.